# Regex for variable string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some strings that I'd like to extract the numbers from. The string can have a variety of formats such that:

`something on the wing$(0.55) $0.75 $(0.10)`

I'd like to capture the groups such that the end result is:

1. something on the wing
2. (0.55)
3. 0.75
4. (0.10)

I'll never know if there is going to be a '$' or if the number will be a decimal or how many numbers I need to capture (i.e., in this example there are 3 numbers but there could be 4). Right now I have `([\w\s]*)([\W\d]*)` which captures the string and the values:

1. something on the wing
2. $(0.55) $0.75 $(0.10)

But cannot seem to parse the individual values.

Comment: `I'll never know if there is going to be a '$' or how many values I need to capture. `, unclear..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may `split` with the following regex:

```
/\s*\$?(\(?\d*\.?\d+\)?)\s*/
```

The [pattern](https://regex101.com/r/cL0rH7/3) matches

- `\$?` - an optional `$` (since it may be present or absent, but we need to exclude it from the results)
- `(\(?\d*\.\d+\)?)` - Group 1 (captured values are output to the resulting array with `split`) matching a float value inside optional parentheses:

  - `\(?` - an optional `(`
  - `\d*` - zero or more digits
  - `\.?` - an **optional** `.`
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
  - `\)?` - an optional `)`
- `\s*` - will match zero or more whitespaces (so as not to trim the elements of the resulting array)

See the JS demo:

```js
var re = /\s*\$?(\(?\d*\.?\d+\)?)\s*/; 
var str = 'something on the wing$(0.55) $0.75 $(0.10)';
var res = str.split(re).filter(Boolean);   // .filter(Boolean) will remove empty values
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(res,0,4) + "</pre>";
```

Comment: If I wanted to make the decimal optional would it just be ``/\s*\$?(\(?\d*(\.)?\d+\)?)\s*/``?

Comment: @Jeff no , it's `\d+(?:\.\d+)?`

Comment: So, I add ``\,?`` to allow for commas too, but this makes it fall apart on numbers with 2+ commas (i.e., 123,456,789). I changed the regex to ``/\s*\$?(\(?\d*[.,]?\d+\)?)\s*/g`` but that doesn't work. I'm assuming because this pattern assumes one set of digits before and one after. How can I specify that the pattern of digit/comma can occur multiple times?

Comment: The pattern for numbers with optional digit grouping symbol is `(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d*)(?:\.\d+)?`

Answer (score 2):

I should do splitting.

```js
alert('something on the wing$(0.55) $0.75 $(0.10)'.split(/\s*\$\s*/))
```

Comment: `I'll never know if there is going to be a '$' or how many values I need to capture.`

Comment: @ritesht93 then he must provide an example for that case.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: When it is stated in a clear way, an example is redundant. It is clear OP needs the numbers in optional parentheses and what is surrounding them.

Comment: then why he wants `something on the wing` ?

Comment: I am no psychic medium/mentalist :) Let OP explain.

Answer (score 1):

Even without any captures this will most probably do the job the way you wanted. Since there are no capture parenthesis it will capture as many data figures following the sentence and return in an array.

```
^[\w\s]+|[\d\.()]+?(?=\s|$)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/19-gAX7gEY4VvmA9)

```js
var r = /^[\w\s]+|[\d\.()]+?(?=\s|$)/g,
    s = "something on the wing$(0.55) $0.75 $(0.10) $12.75 €(4.25)",
    m = s.match(r);
document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(m, null, 2) + "</pre>");
```

Comment: Thanks, I need to keep those parens though as they indicate negative numbers.

Comment: @Jeff then the corrected one above seems fine with your data.